# How to use __bridge for ARC correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I changed the code shown below into ARC compatible.

I just changed it as Xcode suggested, and it doesn't show error on Xcode.  But the code crushes once the event happens.  Does anybody have an idea to fix this?

I'm not sure if this crush happens because of acapela SDK, or not.

**This is non ARC code, it works fine.**

```
void MyInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState) {

    AcapelaSpeech* anAcapelaSpeech = *(AcapelaSpeech**)inClientData;

    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {

        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:NO];
        status = AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    }
    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {

        status = AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:YES];
    }
}
```

**This is ARC compatible, but it crushes on [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:NO];.**

```
void MyInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState) {

    AcapelaSpeech* anAcapelaSpeech = (__bridge_transfer AcapelaSpeech*)inClientData;

    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {

        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:NO];
        AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    }
    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {

        AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:YES];
    }
}
```

**Additional info.**
I'm using Acapela audio SDK, audio interruption code is shown on the 9.Interruptions of this PDF.  http://www.ecometrixem.com/cms-assets/documents/44729-919017.acapela-for-iphone.pdf

This is the screenshot for the crush.
[image]

**SOLVED**
This code works, thanks.

```
void MyInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState) {

    AcapelaSpeech *anAcapelaSpeech = (__bridge id) (*(void **) inClientData);

    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {

        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:NO];
        AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    }
    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {

        AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
        [anAcapelaSpeech setActive:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: __bridge_retained is for CF objects and objects that require a reference to be kept to them.  __bridge is used for NSObjects who don't require retention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
id asObject = (__bridge id) (*(void **) ptr);
```